# Textbox background image pushing out in IE 6 & IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Please see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/P47sa/1/) jsFiddle example. The background image I have used on textbox pushes out of view in IE when you type in long values:

[image]

**Solution (in case jsfiddle gets deleted)**

CSS

```
#txt_services_by_zip_code_search{
    border: none;
    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    width: 95px;
    padding:0 5px;
    background: transparent
}
#txt_services_by_zip_code_search_wrapper {
    background: transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/quh2W.gif') no-repeat 0 -25px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="txt_services_by_zip_code_search_wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="services_by_zip_code_search" id="txt_services_by_zip_code_search" class="txt_services_by_zip_code_search" />
</div>
```

Comment: The background image I have used on textbox pushes out of view in IE when you type in long values. How to resolve that bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic IE bug..

There is no clean workaround. You have to wrap the input in another element such as a `div`, and apply the `background` to that instead.

**See in IE7:** http://jsfiddle.net/P47sa/3/

Here's a random page on the Internet that agrees with me: http://blogs.creative-jar.com/post/Input-backgrounds-scrolling-in-IE.aspx

If your page makes heavy use of JavaScript/jQuery, you could use that to apply the fix instead of cluttering up the HTML.