# Internet explorer and css background-image doesn't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Textbox background image pushing out in IE 6 & IE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740240/textbox-background-image-pushing-out-in-ie-6-ie-7)

I have some CSS that works fine in Firefox, Chrome and other browsers but which is failing to render the same in IE.

I use this CSS over input fields, and it shows perfectly in all browsers - until I write in the field. In Internet Explorer when I write past the end of the field the background repeats.  Here is my code:

```
.web_contact_text
{
position:relative;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
width:244px;
height:65px;
line-height:65px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:-3px;
left:10px;
background:transparent;
background-image:url("imagenes/contactar/campo_back_text.png");
border:0px solid;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:18px;
color:#000000;
cursor:pointer;
cursor:hand;
}



<input type="text" name="contactar_nombre" class="web_contact_text" value="Insertar Nombre" title="Insertar Nombre" onclick="this.value=''">
```

**BAD**

[image: Bad version (IE)]

**OK IN OTHER BROWNSERS**

[image: Good version (other browsers)]

The problem it´s with the background image , when you use input field , text , etc , the image used as background repit when you writte more of size of this input field , this thing only happend in internet explorer , and when you writte more no respect thhe background and repit this all time no fix the background no respect

http://i40.tinypic.com/4vs187.png

Comment: IE 8 , background-image in inputs repit when writte more of width of field , regards

Comment: The problem you can see here : http://i40.tinypic.com/4vs187.png

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: yes........................:)

Comment: You can see here the problem http://i40.tinypic.com/4vs187.png

Comment: How wide is your image? You need to set the width of the input to the same width or else it will run over the end of your image, change `width:244px;` to `width:width of image;`

Comment: the size of the input text and size the image it´s the same the problem it´s with IE

Comment: I don't understand, you'll need to add a fiddler to take this forward as I'm unsure what your expecting.

Comment: When you put background image in input text you can write over this and no see the classic input texyou see backkgroundimage of that input text , ok , this works in all brownsers but in internet explorer when you writte over the field with this background image , this background image repit when writte over the field i put you image for undersand more this http://i40.tinypic.com/4vs187.png , regards

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740240/textbox-background-image-pushing-out-in-ie-6-ie-7

Answer (score 0):

```
.web_contact_text 
{
  background: url(filename.jpg);
  position: relative;
}
```

Occasionally this won't work, so another solution is to assign a width or a height to the element with the background image. You may not want to assign a height or width, so a solution is to assign a height of 1% for Internet Explorer. Because IE interprets height as min-height this CSS rule won't affect the appearance:

```
.web_contact_text
{
  background: url(filename.jpg);
  height: 1%;
}

html>body .web_contact_text 
{
  height: auto;
}
```

The `height: 1%` CSS command is cancelled out by the `height: auto` CSS command. Internet Explorer doesn't understand `html>body`, so by inserting this in front of the second CSS rule this whole CSS rule is ignored by IE.

**source:** [link](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml)

Comment: The problem it´s with the background image , when you use over input field , text , etc , the image used as background repit when you writte more of size of this input field , this thing only happend in internet explorer , actually in IE 8.0

Comment: @GerardoGuzmánMiro try `background-size: 100px 100px;` /* give desired width and height */ this may work. and also `background-repeat:no-repeat`. reply me if it doesnt work.

Comment: @GerardoGuzmánMiro Just asking, have you declared `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your HTML page? you may knew this.

Comment: You can see the problem when use background images in internet explorer http://i40.tinypic.com/4vs187.png